# jasmine window.location.reload in ngOnDestroy

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine

`public ngOnDestroy(): void { window.location.reload(); }`

How can I unit test this? All answers I found didn't work or only worked when the test was the only one executed. It looks like jasmine is inherently calling ngOnDestroy() outside of a test suite scope. Mocking ngOnDestroy() and writing a console.log into the real thing also always resulted in a console output.

specs:

- karma-jasmine: 4.0.2
- jasmine-core: 4.0.0
- angular: 12

**For completion, I tried the following:**

(also checked every possibility in beforeAll(), afterEach() and afterAll())

- mock ngOnDestroy():

  ```
  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(Component);
    fixture.componentInstance.ngOnDestroy = () => null,
  }
  ```
- spyOn ngOnDestroy():

  ```
  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(Component);
    spyOn(fixture.componentInstance, 'ngOnDestroy').and.callFake(() => null);
  }
  ```
- spyOn fixture.destroy():

  ```
  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(Component);
    spyOn(fixture, 'destroy').and.callFake(() => null);
  ```
- spyOn a component function:

  ```
  // component:
     public ngOnDestroy(): void { this.reload(); }
     public reload(): void { window.location.reload; }

  // test:
     beforeEach(() => {
       fixture = TestBed.createComponent(Component);
       spyOn(fixture.componentInstance, 'reload').and.callFake(() => null);
  ```
- spyOn reload:

  ```
   beforeEach(() => {
     fixture = TestBed.createComponent(Component);
     spyOn(window.location, 'reload').and.callFake(() => null);
  ```
- mock reload:

  ```
   beforeEach(() => {
     fixture = TestBed.createComponent(component);
     window.location.reload = () => null,
  ```
- mock location (this one gives wild results...):

  ```
  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(Component);
    window.location = {reload: () => null};
  ```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`window` is your dependency, therefore, it should be injected as any other dependency, for example, as a token:

```js
export const WINDOW = new InjectionToken('WINDOW');
```

then, in the module of `Component`, you need to provide it:

```js
@NgModule({
  // ...
  providers: [
    {
      provide: WINDOW,
      useValue: window,
    },
  ],
  // ...
})
```

then, inject it in your `Component`, you need to inject it as dependency:

```js
export class Component {
  constructor(@Inject(WINDOW) private window: Window) {}

  public ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this.window.location.reload(); // add this.
  }
}
```

Now, you can mock it in your tests:

```js
beforeEach(() => {
  return TestBed.configureTestingModule({
    declarations: [Component],
    providers: [
      {
        provide: WINDOW,
        useValue: {
          location: {
            reload: () => undefined, // or a spy
          },
        },
      },
    ],
  }).compileComponents();
});
```

Profit!